# Avoid rapid clicking on button in website

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on HTML part. I have a button. On clicking that button used toggleSlide() to div.
If I click that button rapidly for 4-5 times drop down gets animates multiple time. I want to avoid it.
Thanks in advance.

```
<button name="dropdown" id="dropdown"/>
<div id="dropdown1">
   Dropdown text here
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#dropdown").click(function(){
      $("#dropdown1").toggleSlide();
   })
})
```

Problem:
On clicking multiple time at a moment (rapidly). It gets animate as much time I clicked that button.

Comment: Disable the button onclick. After a set period of time, reenable it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to cancel the clicks, you should [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) the animation. Basic example below

```js
$("#dropdown").on("click", function() {
  $("#dropdown1").stop().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#dropdown1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="dropdown">toggle</button>
<div id="dropdown1"></div>
```